# Mocking Knex with Sinon

Tags: node.js, chai, sinon

I'm trying to write unit tests for my NodeJs app with chai and sinon, but having problems with mocking my knex query builder.

I instansiate Knex as `database` in my app.js file and then attach it to my context in my app.

The function I'd like to write my unit test for gets called by a graphQL query and `database` is passed as a parameter from the context. The query is then constructed in that function. I've created an short example below. (I'm using js not typescript)

```
module.exports = async ({ database, data }) => {
  const queryObject = database.table('nice')
    .withSchema('very')
    .select(['some_col_1', 'some_col_2', 'some_col_3']);
  
  if (data) {
    queryObject.where('some_col_1', data.something);
  }
  
  const foo = await queryObject 
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log(err)
    });

  //Do something with foo...
};
```

I've spent the whole day trying to get it to work, but I'm not having any luck. The closest I've came was getting an error saying `queryObject is not a function`.

The other examples have repositories setup, but I build the query in the function that needs a specific query.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to solve my own problem using `mock-knex`
[Link to mock-knex](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mock-knex)

This is all in my unit test. Imported the following:

```
const knex = require('knex');
const mod = require('mock-knex');
const tracker = require('mock-knex').getTracker();
```

Then I made the mock DB connection

```
const db = knex({
  client: 'mssql',
  connection: {
    host: '127.0.0.1',
    user: 'mockKnex',
    password: 'mockKnex',
    database: 'mockKnex',
  },
});
```

Then implemented the `before`,`after`, `beforeEach`, `afterEach` functions.

```
describe('Unit tests', () => {
  before((done) => {
    mod.mock(db);
    done();
  });

  after((done) => {
    mod.unmock(db);
    done();
  });

  beforeEach((done) => {
    tracker.install();
    done();
  });

  afterEach((done) => {
    tracker.uninstall();
    done();
  });
});
```

Finally in my test case I did the following

```
it('Test 1', (done) => {
    tracker.on('query', (query) => {
      expect(query.method)
        .to
        .equal('select');
      query.response([
        {
          something1: 'A',
          something2: 'B',
          something3: 'C',
          something4: 'D',
          something5: 'E',
        },
      ]);
    });

    someFunction(
      {
        database: db,
        data: { something: '1' },
      },
    ).catch((res) => {
      assert.equal(res.message, 'Something');
      done();
    });
  });
```

After this I was able to manupilate the select query by changing the array object of something1..5 to get the response I was looking for.